# SQL: How to get all tables' columns & keys + the primary key?

Tags: mysql, innodb, schema, primary-key, information-schema

#### Database Info

MySQL 8.0.22
InnoDB

#### The Goal

I'm trying to get all tables in a database, with their column definitions and foreign keys, and primary keys on their own row for each table group.

Given the following tables

```
create database test;
use test;

CREATE TABLE authors (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
CREATE TABLE books (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  author_id int NOT NULL,
  title varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  summary varchar(255),
  FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES authors(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
CREATE TABLE authors_books (
  author_id int NOT NULL,
  book_id int NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES authors(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES books(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  PRIMARY KEY(author_id, book_id)
);
```

The end result should look something like:

```
authors
id,int,no,auto_increment
name,varchar(255),no,UNIQUE
PK(id)

books
id,int
author_id,int,FK->authors.id
title,varchar(255),UNIQUE
summary,varchar(255),NULL
PK(id)

authors_books
author_id,int,FK->authors.id
book_id,int,FK->books.id
PK(author_id,book_id)
```

Now, the following query gets me everything except the keys. It's a mess in mysql output, but running it with the command helps it look digestible.

```
mysql -u root -p -NBre "SELECT CONCAT_WS('\n', table_name, GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT_WS(',', column_name, column_type)
    ORDER BY ordinal_position
    SEPARATOR '\n'
  ),
  '\n'
)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'test'
GROUP BY table_name"
```

I've tried many combinations to get the keys, but could only get as close as the following.

```
SELECT a.table_name, a.column_name, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(',', a.column_type, b.constraint_name, b.ordinal_position ) SEPARATOR '|') as the_rest
FROM columns a
LEFT JOIN key_column_usage b
  ON (a.table_name = b.table_name AND a.column_name = b.column_name)
WHERE b.table_schema = 'test'
GROUP BY a.table_name, a.column_name
ORDER BY a.table_name;
```

Which gives:

```
| TABLE_NAME    | COLUMN_NAME | the_rest                                 |
|---------------|-------------|------------------------------------------|
| authors       | id          | int,PRIMARY,1                            |
| authors       | name        | varchar(255),name,1                      |
| authors_books | author_id   | int,PRIMARY,1|int,authors_books_ibfk_1,1 |
| authors_books | book_id     | int,PRIMARY,2|int,authors_books_ibfk_2,1 |
| books         | author_id   | int,books_ibfk_1,1                       |
| books         | id          | int,PRIMARY,1                            |
| books         | title       | varchar(255),title,1                     |
```

Notice, `books.summary` is missing, so I'm thinking all fields without a constraint will be missing from the results.

Another thing is when a primary key is a composite key, such as in the bridge table `authors_books`, they should not be part of the `GROUP_CONCAT` in the 3rd column but instead be its own record at the end of the `table_name` group.

I might be on the wrong track but.. **How can I also get the columns that don't have key constraints, plus the table's primary key as its own row?**

#### Update

This query from @J.D. also includes the columns with no constraints, (modified to exclude the 3000+ irrelevant results)

```
SELECT c.table_name, c.column_name, k.the_rest
FROM columns c
JOIN (
  SELECT a.table_name, a.column_name, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(',', a.column_type, b.constraint_name, b.ordinal_position ) SEPARATOR '|') as the_rest
  FROM columns a
  LEFT JOIN key_column_usage b
    ON (a.table_name = b.table_name AND a.column_name = b.column_name AND b.table_schema = 'test')
  GROUP BY a.table_name, a.column_name
  ORDER BY a.table_name
) as k
  ON c.table_name = k.table_name AND c.column_name = k.column_name
WHERE c.table_schema = 'test'
```

However

- it still does not put the primary key(s) into its own row
- my modification somehow removed the foreign keys from the `the_rest` column

here's what it looks like:

```
| TABLE_NAME    | COLUMN_NAME | the_rest            |
|---------------|-------------|---------------------|
| authors       | id          | int,PRIMARY,1       |
| authors       | name        | varchar(255),name,1 |
| authors_books | author_id   | int                 |
| authors_books | book_id     | int                 |
| books         | author_id   | int                 |
| books         | id          | int,PRIMARY,1       |
| books         | summary     | varchar(255)        |
| books         | title       | varchar(255)        |
```

This query from the resource @J.D. linked shows the keys with the primary keys on their own row and grouped for composite keys. **But, if the column is the *first* key in a composite key it's not included in the set** as its own record. Which is bad because because you can't see the foreign key info (linked table and column).

```
select tab.table_schema as database_name,
    sta.index_name as pk_name,
    group_concat(distinct sta.column_name order by sta.column_name) as 'columns',
    tab.table_name,
    sta.non_unique as is_FK
from information_schema.tables as tab
inner join information_schema.statistics as sta
        on sta.table_schema = tab.table_schema
        and sta.table_name = tab.table_name
        -- and sta.index_name = 'primary'
where tab.table_schema = 'test'
    and tab.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
group by tab.table_name, sta.index_name, sta.non_unique
order by tab.table_name;
```

And the output:

```
| database_name | pk_name   | columns           | TABLE_NAME    | is_FK |
|---------------|-----------|-------------------|---------------|-------|
| test          | name      | name              | authors       |     0 |
| test          | PRIMARY   | id                | authors       |     0 |
| test          | book_id   | book_id           | authors_books |     1 |
| test          | PRIMARY   | author_id,book_id | authors_books |     0 |
| test          | author_id | author_id         | books         |     1 |
| test          | PRIMARY   | id                | books         |     0 |
| test          | title     | title             | books         |     0 |
```

Comment: Just checking, is PostgreSQL related at all to your question?...if not could you please remove that tag and only tag things that are relevant. E.g. schema, primary-key, and your version of MySQL would be most helpful.

Comment: I included it because I'd like an SQL database-agnostic solution, or at least one that works with the latest versions of mysql and postgresql. I can remove it if you think it's irrelevant?

Comment: Diving into the *information schemas* is not going to have a database-agnostic solution since there is no standard (being that it's not an ANSI SQL requirement on how to provide that information). I'd recommend asking the question specific to the database system, engine, and version you're using, as each of these can affect the answers, and are generally the level of detail required on here to be able to answer most questions.

Comment: How about `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename`?

Comment: I'm considering that as a last result, via *mysqldump*, but that'd be a shame since the data needed is in the database, already parsed...

Answer (score 1):

The reason your last query is filtering out columns without **constraints** like `books.summary` is because your `WHERE` clause inadvertently filters out anything that doesn't match on the `JOIN` clause. You should actually move the predicate from the `WHERE` clause up into your `JOIN` clause's predicates like so:

```
SELECT a.table_name, a.column_name, 
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(',', a.column_type, b.constraint_name, b.ordinal_position ) SEPARATOR '|')
FROM columns a
LEFT JOIN key_column_usage b
  ON (a.table_name = b.table_name AND a.column_name = b.column_name AND b.table_schema = 'test')
GROUP BY a.table_name, a.column_name
ORDER BY a.table_name;
```

This will ensure your `LEFT JOIN` returns all rows from the `columns` table and will `NULL` out any values of the columns in the `key_column_usage` table that don't match on the `JOIN` (i.e. the rows where the `columns` don't have a **constraint**).

Also, have you seen this article [List all primary keys (PKs) and their columns in MySQL database](https://dataedo.com/kb/query/mysql/list-all-primary-keys-and-their-columns#toc_1) and tried the sample code from it? Although they're filtering on **primary keys** you can adjust that filter and likely access other **constraints** like **foreign keys** as well. Please see a modified query below:

```
select tab.table_schema as database_schema,
    sta.index_name --as pk_name,
    sta.seq_in_index as column_id,
    sta.column_name,
    tab.table_name
from information_schema.tables as tab
left join information_schema.statistics as sta
    on sta.table_schema = tab.table_schema
    and sta.table_name = tab.table_name
    --and sta.index_name = 'primary' --commented out to get all indexes (probably want to filter on certain types though
where tab.table_schema = 'your database name'
    and tab.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
order by tab.table_name,
    column_id;
```

Comment: Thanks J.D. this is helpful; The resources looked promising, but I still wasn't able to get the desired output even after working with it all day. I updated the post with my results. And I'm on mysql 8, InnoDB.

Comment: @slanden No problem! If I get a chance I'll try to see if there's anything else I can suggest to help get you across the finish line. I don't have a MySQL instance to test on, so I'm flying a little blind.